# py2exe error with Python 3.4: Errno2 , missing file 'run-py3 .4-win32.exe'

Tags: python, py2exe, python-3.4

It looks like py2exe is looking for the file "run-py3
.4-win32.exe'", the folder mentioned in the error exists, but it looks like no file is there. This is a simple "Helloworld.py" application, just learning how to build exe's. I installed the source ( https://pypi.python.org/pypi/py2exe/0.9.2.2 ) and it looked like it built fine.

Any ideas of where to start?

```
...\buildtry1> py -3.4 setup.py py2exe

running py2exe

1 missing Modules

? readline                            imported from cmd, code, pdb
Building 'dist\helloworld.exe'.
error: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C:\\Python34\\lib\\site- packages\\py2exe-0.9.2.2-py3.4.egg\\py2exe\\run-py3.4-win32.exe'
```

setup.py and helloworld.py are in the same directory

**Update**

Turned off virus scan and reinstalled PY2EXE, all is well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I disabled virus scan, deleted my py2exe folder in python34 directory. Reinstalled py2exe and it ran without error.

Answer (score 1):

There is a blank space in your path directory. Just after "sites- ", check if this is your problem.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

Update py2exe. If that doesn't work:

Install python 3.3 or any other python 3 version suitable for py2exe. run it with py -3.3 setup.py py2exe